# Centering a border that is smaller than its div

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have two divs that are col-xs-12 wide. There is no margin between them so they touch. I would like to add a border between them, like the image on the right (what I have currently is on the left).

[image]

I tried adding a 1 px height 11-wide column and centering it, but of course you can see a gap between the two rows on each side of the border.

Here's a [jfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yjtrk00o/1/) of the whole thing.

```
<div class="row top-buffer-10">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
        <div class="header-text">
        <p style="font-size:130%"><b>%REGION%</b></p>
        <p style="padding-bottom:15px;">(currently selected)</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row top-buffer-10">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
        <div class="img-with-text">
            <img style="margin-top:5px;" src="img/gsd_list_contact.png" alt="itscl" />
            <p style="font-size:90%;padding-left:0px;"><b>PHONE:</b> %LOCAL_PHONE%<br>
                    <b>TOLL FREE:</b> %TOLL_FREE%<br>
                    <b>LANGUAGE:</b> %LANGUAGE%
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

These are the two relevant divs to look out for.

There seems to be a little confusion, I want the border to be small than the div, as in, not just adding border top or border bottom.

[image]

See how the border doesn't quite reach the edges of the div. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a possible solution: https://jsfiddle.net/yjtrk00o/4/

**EDIT:**

- add a css called division as shown below
- In your HTML, add the line `<hr class="division"/>` just above the `<div class="img-with-text">`

**CSS**

```
.division{
    border-top:1px solid #D3D3D3;   
    margin-top:0px;
    margin-bottom:0px;
    margin-left:10px;
    margin-right:10px;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="col-xs-12">
<hr class="division"/>
<div class="img-with-text">
```

Comment: Please check my edit, I do not want the border to span the length of the div.

Comment: @WillNasby, updated the answer. Please see the edit.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if it's the desired effect you're after, but have you tried the following:

`<div class="img-with-text" style="border-top: 1px solid black;">`

Obviously you can fiddle with colour etc, or add that into the css class.

EDIT:

perhaps this then:

`<div class="col-xs-12">
    <div style="margin: 0 10px; display: block; height: 1px; background: #000;"></div>
    <div class="img-with-text">`

You can play with the margin to give you the offset from the edges you want. Probably not the most elegant solution, but seems to get the visual result you're after?

Comment: Please check my edit, I do not want the border to span the length of the div.

Comment: Ah sorry! The line was a bit light in colour so i didn't quite see that :)

Comment: I've added an edit which will hopefully be useful